# How to get output from a web service from a python script in Azure ML

Tags: python, json, web-services, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm new to Azure ML and I'm trying to implement a python script in Azure ML. I'm trying to deploy the web services, but I'm getting only a string as output.

When I run the python script alone, I'm getting the result, but when implemented in Web service, i'm only getting a statement saying "Execution ok"  . Please let me know, how to go about it.

```
The output returns a Json format.
```

Following is my output from Python script:

```
User Patterns
[{"Jane": [{"Thermostat": 20, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 6, "Minute": 43}], 
"John": [{"Thermostat": 18, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 0, "Minute": 15}], 
"Jen": [{"Thermostat": 22, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 10, "Minute": 1}]}]

Missed Patterns
[{"Jane": [], "John": [], "Jen": []}]
Patternsssssssssss [{"Jane": [{"Thermostat": 20, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 6, 
"Minute": 43}], "John": [{"Thermostat": 18, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 0, 
"Minute": 15}], "Jen": [{"Thermostat": 22, "Days": [1, 2], "Hour": 10, 
"Minute": 1}]}]
```

Comment: Can you please publish the experiment as a private entry to the gallery and share the link here?
Then we can look on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please make sure you have connected web service output to the first output port of Execute Python script